# Forms in Chrome - strange css rendering

Tags: html, forms, css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Today I've came across strange behavior that I never met before.

I built this website on Bootstrap 3.2.0. When I put any `<form>` in the code, Chrome (Mac - Mavericks) gets acting strange on reloads. Hard to describe - it has render all stuff in main.css very slow after the whole content is ready a rendered.

Here's the link: http://www.cloud-it.sk/sources/pooltechnika/shop-grid.html

Has anyone met this glitch before?

Comment: I see that you used CSS3 animations in your code. Make sure these animation are only set for the properties and elements on which you want them.

Comment: Please DO NOT link you your website. Here's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have managed to work this out.

The presence of form tags in HMTL combined with color transitions anywhere in the css causes a transitions on every element to fire on load.